# Tikz Graph Example – all nodes stacked

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I try to reproduce the `\graph` example of the pgf manual 2.10 page 208:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph {a -> { b , c } -> d};
\pgfversion
\end{document}
```

All nodes `(a, b, c, d)` are placed on top of each other as shown in the following figure.

[image]

I use TeX Live 2012 under Ubuntu 12.04 (through ppa-backports). Is it my TeX setup or do I forget to include some tikz libraries?

Comment: Looks ok for me (miktex, pgf version 2.10-cvs).

Comment: I have the same effect under SuSe 12.1 with TeX Live 2011 (pgf also 2.10).

Comment: I have the *cvs* version. On another PC with the standard pgf version 2.10 I get the same problematic output as you.

Comment: I also got the same problematic output.

Comment: with current TL2012 it is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pgf-manual of pgf 2.10 says nothing about the `graphs` library and its `\graph` macro (on page 208, we find the section 17.4, *"Anchoring a Matrix"*)!

So, your example of the page 208 comes from a **newer** version of the pgf manual (surely a CVS version...)!

Your example can be compiled with pgf 2.10 because pgf 2.10 contains some files planned for the future (as `tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex`). But, these files are experimental and old.

Comment: That's it. I did not care about this “-cvs“ thing. Downloading the cvs into the local textree helped.